# MYSQL - count(id) with 2 different clause in 1 query (with Inner Join, NOT GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables (customer & orders) contains :

```
// Customer Table
customer_id     customer_name     customer_address
     1            customer01          address01
     2            customer02          address02
     3            customer03          address03
     4            customer04          address04
     5            customer05          address05

// Orders Table
order_id    customer_id    order_status
    1             1           rejected
    2             1           success
    3             2           success
    4             1           success
    5             1           pending
    6             2           success
    7             2           pending
    8             3           pending
```

So, in the Order table I had :

- customer01 had `2 success`, `1 rejected` and `1 pending`
- customer02 had `2 success` and `1 pending`
- customer03 only had `1 pending`

**EXPECTATION :** Result that I need

```
customer_id   Customer_name (success)   order_status
     1           customer01 (2)           pending
     2           customer02 (2)           pending
     3           customer03 (0)           pending
```

**My Query :** using sample data on SQLfiddle

```
SELECT o.order_id, c.customer_id, CONCAT(c.customer_name, " (", (SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM orders WHERE order_status = 'success'),")") as "Customer Name (success order)", o.order_status
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE o.order_status = 'pending'
ORDER BY c.customer_id ASC;
```

**RESULT**

```
customer_id   Customer_name (success)   order_status
     1           customer01 (4)           pending
     2           customer02 (4)           pending
     3           customer03 (4)           pending
```

---

**EDIT** : Remove SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing link between subquery and main query to get the related count

```
(SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM orders WHERE order_status = 'success'
 and customer_id = c.customer_id   --- you need to link the sub and the mainquery
)
```

Comment: Ah, i see. I used Inner join after from and that said too many rows. I forgot changes it to join in `WHERE` clause. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how the status is calculated.  And, your data on the SQL Fiddle is different from the data in the question.

But I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT c.c_id, 
       CONCAT(c.c_name, " (", SUM(o.o_status = 'success'), ")") as "Customer Name (Success Order Count)",
       min(o.o_status)
FROM customer c INNER JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.c_id = o.c_id 
GROUP BY c.c_id ASC, c.c_name;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90d5fe/9).